# Editing Metadata on Joomla

Tags: joomla

I can not edit metadata on Joomla CMS. Where do si located the metadata file , the one who displays information on the description html meta tag ?

I need to edit by hand until discobver what is wrong.

Thank's in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Joomla is a database driven CMS, so metadata for articles, modules etc is stored in the database with the content of the article etc.

The only other meta data is the Global site metadata and that is stored in the `configuration.php`. The easiest way to change that is via the `Site` menu and the `Global Configuration` menu item (in Joomla! 2.5 it's in the `Site` tab of the Global Configuration).

It is not advisable to edit `configuration.php` directly as a single character can break the configuration file and take the website down.

If you really must edit `configuration.php` be aware that Joomla sets it to `444` permission after every change, i.e. **read only** or to to put it another way unwriteable. Using your websites control panel (*cPanel or similar*) you will have to change it to be writeable before you open it to make changes.

*Don't forget to change it back.*

[Joomla's recommended permisions](http://docs.joomla.org/What_are_the_recommended_file_and_directory_permissions?) are:

- Files should be `644` and
- Directories should be `755`

Joomla! also has an article on [Verifying permissions](http://docs.joomla.org/Verifying_permissions)

Comment: I do enter in Site and GLobal configuration. When i do edit the metadata (changing the new busines location) it does not save the file, and show an error message: it is not possible to open the file to write,

Comment: This can happer because of file permission or ownership.  The file permissions should be 755 and the owner should be the user that runs apache.  So either chmod or chown will solve.

Comment: Files should be `644`, directories should be `755`, Joomla locks the configuration file with `444` every time it writes it out.